# performItemClick doesn't start animation

Tags: android

I'm creating a ListView with many item, each row of ListView contains a TextView and a "Remove" button, when click on Remove button (not click on the row), that row should show the toast, run the animation and remove from the list but it only show the toast (It works well when I click on the row)

This is my code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.Animation.AnimationListener;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    String[] items = new String[20];
    ListView lv;
    MyAdapter mAdapter;
    ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
    private int position;
    Animation ani;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            items[i] = String.valueOf(i + 1);
            data.add(items[i]);
        }

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getApplication(), R.layout.custom_row, data);
        lv.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        ani = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.animator.fadeout);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, final int arg2, long arg3) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have clicked on item " + arg2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                arg1.startAnimation(ani);
                ani.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                        mAdapter.remove(arg2);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        ArrayList<String> data;

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View v = inflater.inflate(layout, parent, false);
            TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            tv.setText(data.get(position));
            Button bt = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button1);
            bt.setOnClickListener(new MyClick(this, position));
            return v;
        }

        class MyClick implements View.OnClickListener {
            MyAdapter p;
            int i;

            public MyClick(MyAdapter parent, int pos) {
                p = parent;
                i = pos;
            }

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                lv.performItemClick(lv.getAdapter().getView(i, null, null), i, i);
            }
        }

        public void remove(int pos) {
            data.remove(pos);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        int layout;

        public MyAdapter(Context c, int l, ArrayList<String> data_name) {
            super(c, l, data_name);
            layout = l;
            data = data_name;
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: where is yours animation specific code?? also visit https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations

Comment: here ani = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.animator.fadeout);
As I said if I click on the row, the animation works then remove the row from the list, but if I click on the button on the row, it only shows the toast

Answer (score 0):

Modify your `onClick` callback method in `MyClick` class like below:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    lv.performItemClick(lv.getChildAt(i), i, i);
}
```

Because `p.getView(i, null, null)` will inflate a new View that isn't the `item` in `ListView`, so you should use `lv.getChildAt(i)` to get the actual `item`.

Comment: I've just figured out the solution without using performItemClick, thank you anyway :)